# How to create composer library package that auto generates code when included

Tags: php, github, package, composer-php, auto-generate

Every time I create a new PHP project I basically use the same MVC folder structure that I adopted and like, I use the same base classes, interfaces, and the same PDO DAL implementation.
When I'm creating a new project I copy&paste all the needed files to the new project in addition to few changes, like changes to namespaces (to match the new project name) etc.

I thought, why not creating a simple script to copy those files and folders, and make the additional changes.
So now, when I create a new project I just run the script and the code is generated automatically, which is much nicer.

And then I thought, I want it to be even simpler. I don't want to save the code in my computer, I want to save it on Github, and since I use and love composer, I thought I will make the Github project a composer package.
But when trying to implement it I realized that I can't make the new composer package auto generate the code that I want, or at least I don't know how to make it do that.
I tried googling it with no success.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any need to generate code here. Simply add your skeleton files to your Git repository and use Composer's [`create-project`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) feature. See the third point:

> You can use Composer to create new projects from an existing package. This is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a composer install of the vendors.
>
> There are several applications for this:
>
> 1. You can deploy application packages.
> 2. You can check out any package and start developing on patches for example.
> 3. Projects with multiple developers can use this feature to bootstrap the initial application for development.

An example of a major PHP project that supports this approach is [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). From its [installation instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation):

> ### Via Composer
>
> The Laravel framework utilizes [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) for installation and dependency management. If you haven't already, start by [installing Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).
>
> Now you can install Laravel by issuing the following command from your terminal:
>
> ```
> composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
> ```
>
> This command will download and install a fresh copy of Laravel in a new `your-project-name` folder within your current directory.
>
> If you prefer, you can alternatively download a copy of the [Laravel repository from Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip) manually. Next run the `composer install` command in the root of your manually created project directory. This command will download and install the framework's dependencies.

**Edit:**

To have a script run after `composer create-project` completes you should be able to use a [Composer script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md):

> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable command. Scripts are useful for executing a package's custom code or package-specific commands during the Composer execution process.

You are probably looking for the `post-create-project-cmd` event:

> occurs after the `create-project` command is executed

Depending on whether your script is a static PHP method or a shell executable, you should define it as follows (modified from Composer documentation):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": "MyVendor\\MyClass::postUpdate"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": "my-shell-script arg1 arg2"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the create-project feature as suggested. It really copied all the needed files to a new project. But my problem is the changes I need to perform, I still need to do it manually. Is there an option to run some kind of pre script that I wrote? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user3736997, I'm still not sure what you mean by manual changes. You mentioned "changes to namespaces (to match the new project name) etc." in the original question. Is that it?

Comment: yes. I need to change namespaces and few variables. I already wrote a script that makes all the desired changes which works great. My question is how can I include the script to the project and run it automatically when I use create-project feature.